# is there way to ensemble the prediction other than the take the mean average?

Tags: conv-neural-network, voting, ensemble-learning

right now I'm just taking the mean average of 3 models predictions

```
predictions_model = [y_pred_xceptionAug,y_pred_Dense121_Aug,y_pred_resnet50Aug]
predictions = np.mean(predictions_model,axis=0)
```

is there a better way to ensemble other than just take a mean average?

Answer (score 0):

One neural network based approach is to use the 3 model predictions as input to a further neural network.

More advanced approaches include [bootstrap aggregating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning#Bootstrap_aggregating_(bagging)), where each model trains on a subset of the entire dataset before predictions are aggregated across models.